# zend headScript()->appendFile in IE (internet explorer)

Tags: zend-framework

Two lines of script

```
  $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/global.js', 'text/javascript');
  $this->headScript()->appendFile('http://zendbase/js/global.js', 'text/javascript');
```

Firefox runs script by both ways(absolute, root relative)

Internet Explorer only run the Second method of append(absolute), which is with http. which is not a good way. 
when I view source in browser I can see following line is added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/global.js"></script>
```

But browser is not reading. it is really beyond my understanding. It is strange. How can I make first line to work with document root path on all browsers including IE.
Is there any settings in view helper? or something else?

I can use $_Server variables to make it absolute dynamically but i don't want to use absolute path.

Any Idea. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is no error. I checked it in IE6 and IE8.

Comment: same way my ajax call is also not working in IE. if i use $.ajax({
              url: "/client/add/" it does not work in IE. and if use $.ajax({
              url: "http://zendbase/client/add/" it works in every browser? why could be that?

Comment: Can you post an example page?

Comment: Hi Ashley, I am not sure which part should you need. infact it is huge large application with modular structure with doctrine, routers etc....

Comment: View the page on your local host and save the page with the browser and upload to a public place.

Comment: I am gettting the feeling there must be wrong somewhere else. not zend. In my phtml view when I add image tag without "h ttp://zendbase.local/" it does not work. <img src"h ttp://zendbase.local/images/add.png" />  (works fine) <img src"/images/add.png" />  (does not work)

Comment: to check my server(apache) I create an simple html page in public folder of my site with image tag <img src"/images/add.png" />. and it works. so I must be doing something wrong somewhere in zend setting. because i have a different structure( modular) with doctrine. So don't know where is the problem.

Comment: I am still facing the same problem. any one got the solution. even I find similar post on http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Relative-Links-not-working-in-IE-no-images-td662887.html#a3550302

Comment: Post a link to some example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the problem

I removed the baseUrl(); ?>" /> from layout.phtml
and added following line in application.ini
resources.frontController.baseUrl = ""

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths for scripts will definitely work with IE - I have used it numerous times... What is the hostname you are using (e.g. www.example.com)? Your second line of code should not work, because you don't have a valid hostname - http://zendbase won't resolve to anything. Is zendbase a variable?

Comment: depends it can be a local domain within a local dns server and/or a configured /etc/hosts

Comment: "zendbase" is my local domain set in hosts file.

Comment: I guess if your app is never accessed outside your computer/ your company, that hostname makes sense... Have you tried using a hostname with tld - zendhost.com. Maybe IE is chocking with relative path and the hostname?

Comment: yes. I was thinking the same thing. and added the tld zendbase.local but still it is not working on IE. It only works with full http://zendbase.local/... I wish someone else know the solution and and get me out of it. before i figure out myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

For relative static assets (images, JS, CSS, SWF, etc), you should always use the `baseUrl` helper, eg

```
$this->headScript()
     ->appendFile($this->baseUrl('/js/global.js'));
```

If you can see the correct `<script>` tag in source, then the problem is either the path is incorrect (see `baseUrl` helper above) or your JavaScript contains errors.

Comment: I used this as well. but it is not working. Strange thing is that when I use <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/global.js"></script> it does not work in IE. and if I use <script type="text/javascript" src="http://zendbase/js/global.js"></script>
it works in every browser. while zendbase is my domain set in host file. It is really making me crazy.

Comment: I can see the script tag <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/global.js"></script> in IE source view. and there is nothing wrong with my script as it only consist of one line alert("hello word");